# Emacs: Different users, different themes, same init file

Tags: emacs

I use emacs at work, where I usually connect to the system with two different users:

- `myuser`
- `commonuser`

The former is my own personal user, whereas the latter is shared by the whole team to manage an application. <sub>(Irrelevant hint: This is a terrible idea. There are generally better, albeit a bit less obvious, ways to manage privileges. Take it from my experience).</sub>

In order to avoid unfortunate mix-ups, I want to define a separate theme for each user, and define it in their respective init files.

Everything else defined in the init file has to be shared by the two.

### Simple solution

I create a separate init file `/path/to/init/file/.emacs` and created the following `.emacs` file in each user's home directory:

```
(load-file "/path/to/init/file/.emacs")
(load-theme my-favorite-theme)
```

This works like a charm. But of course, that would be too easy!

### New solution needed

I was asked not to modify the `.emacs` file of `commonuser`. I won't go into the details of why, but the fact remains that I had to find a workaround. Here's what I got so far:

1. Wrote a complete `~myuser/.emacs` file, that I will load regardless of the user.
2. Defined an alias for `commonuser` like this:

   ```
   alias emacs='emacs -Q --load ~myuser/.emacs'
   ```

This will make emacs ignore `commonuser`'s init file and load `myuser`'s.

Now my (simple) question is:

**How can I make emacs behave differently according to the user launching it?**

I am looking to do something similar:

```
if [[ $(whoami) == "myuser" ]]; then 
      (load-theme 'theme1)
if [[ $(whoami) == "commonuser" ]]; then 
      (load-theme 'theme2)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Emacs has variables that describe the current hostname and username. Just like you would do [in order to conditionally do something based on the hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549978/elisp-conditional-based-on-hostname), you have the variable `user-login-name` (from the docs: "The user's name, taken from environment variables if possible.").

So, I guess something like this would apply:

```
(when (string-equal user-login-name "myuser")
    (load-theme 'theme1))

(when (string-equal user-login-name "commonuser")
    (load-theme 'theme2))
```